# How to get all posts having custom date

Tags: wordpress

I have added new posts with new custom date. now i want to get all posts in a loop having custom date,how is this possible?
And also i want to know that how can i find out the meta key of the newly added custom field.
i am trying following code but problem is this that i have no idea that what is the "meta_key". i have added new custom field whose slug is the "post_date".please look at following code.
i am unable to get data.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'event-category' => 'bmx racing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' => 'post_date',
        'meta_value' => array(01 - 02 - 2016, 29 - 02 - 2016),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ));
    print_r($loop);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
    }
```

Comment: Check out the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Comment: Don't get caught up in the meta_key and meta_value and compare and type, you aren't checking that, it'll just be confusing. Use the date_query format dingo_d linked